# Hitting a endpoint few times simultaneously could cause problems?

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

Lets imagine you have a endpoint like this in your app(pseudo):

```
app.get('/user/withdrawmoney',(req,res)=>{
 DB.find(req.session.id,(user)=>{
  if(user.balance < 0){
     DB.update()...//Update the balance
    ...//Send user money
   }
 })

})
```

would it not be possbible for the user to withdraw more than one time if the "timing" is right even if he has no balance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. There can be a race condition while you are trying to update the user's balance. Here is a race condition example: [race condition (wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)

One way to solve the race condition issue is to create a "transaction" in mongodb. This would lock your model until your code finishes updating the db.
You can see an example here: [MongoDB Cookbook example](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/)

Comment: Perfekt! Exactly what i was looking for. Interesting how no one ever mentions stuff like this.